# On load Get values from field in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using Google Map [Place Autocomplete Hotel Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) Service to Display All hotels Near User Location.

I made a demo for this and its working fine in my machine.but my requirement is when page loads Get user field data and show nearest hotels on page load.

**e.g**  Currently what happens is it shows nearest hotels only when i type some area/cities in the textbox.

I R&D Code.this is code for init function

```
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: countries['in'].zoom,
          center: countries['in'].center,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        });

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: document.getElementById('info-content')
        });

        // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
        // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
                document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
            });
        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

        // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
        document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
            'change', setAutocompleteCountry);
      }
```

And html of inpu field is

```
  <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text"  />
  </div>
```

So how can I get value and show nearest hotels on load? **e.g**: Value of Textbox is `value=" Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India"` So it gets All hotels Nearest Ahmedabad on page load.

**You Can Check My Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/demoblockchainapi/tuwnm9e7/)**
i Also try Google Geocode

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India" }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
            });
        } else {
          alert("Problem with geolocation");
        }
      });
```

But this not shows Hotels it Set Marker To Ahmedabad only.

Answer (score 0):

You initMap function is not initiated properly.
remove all other source code and verify

```
function initMap() {alert("InitMap");}
```

also, load your googleapi maps js as

```
<script async defer  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
```